# Unity: Compute Shader to calculate closest point to each vertex

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, directx, hlsl, compute-shader

I have a mesh, and an array of points. I want to calculate, for each vertex, the index of the closest point in the array.
I have a routine that works:

```
        for (int i=0;i<vertexPositions.Length;i++)
    {
        float minDist = 100000.0f;
        int index=0;
        float dist;
        for (int a=0;a<pointPositions.Length;a++)
        {
            dist = (vertexPositions[i] - pointPositions[a]).sqrMagnitude;
            if (dist<minDist)
            {
                minDist = dist;
                index = a;
            }
        }
        vertexParameter[i] = index;
    }
```

The `vertexParameter` array contains the desired result. This routine is very slow if there are many vertices, so I wanted to make a Compute Shader that does the exact same thing. But I'm a beginner at Compute Shaders…

This is my Compute Shader code:

```
#pragma kernel ClosestPoint

struct vertexData
{
    float3 position;
    int parameter;
};
struct pointData
{
    float3 position;
    float parameter;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<vertexData> vertex;
StructuredBuffer<pointData> point;


[numthreads(32, 1, 1)]
void ClosestPoint(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    int index;
    float dist;
    float minDist = 1000.0f;
    for (uint i = 0; i < point.Length; i++)
    {
        dist = distance(point[i].position, vertex[id.x].position);
        if (dist < minDist)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            index =  i;
        }

    }
    vertex[id.x].parameter =  index;
}
```

I don't know why, but this code gives erroneous results. The results change if I modify the ThreadGroups in the Dispatch call, so I suppose it might be due to some synchronization issues…?

In case it's needed, this is the script code that calls the shader:

```
        vertex = new ComputeBuffer(vertices.Length, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(vertexData)));
    vertex.SetData(vertices);


    point= new ComputeBuffer(points.Length, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(pointData)));
    point.SetData(points);

    shader.SetBuffer(kernelHandle, "vertex", vertex);
    shader.SetBuffer(kernelHandle, "point", point);
    shader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, 1, 1, 1);
    vertex.GetData(vertices);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexParameter.Length; i++)
    {
        vertexParameter[i] = vertices[i].parameter;
    }
    vertex.Release();
    point.Release();
```

Comment: What is the `dxl` variable in the hlsl code? It doesn't seem to be defined/declared there.

Comment: naming mismatch from previous version, now corrected. Sorry.

Comment: I'm surprised that `point.Length` compiles in hlsl. It might be referring something else accidentally. Try adding an int `count` variable passing in the length of the point buffer using `SetInt`. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Unity/Computing_the_Brightest_Pixel) for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Adding the `count` variable did not change anything. But I somehow partially found a solution. The issue seems to be that I do not Dispatch the correct number of threads. If I set ` [numthreads(32, 1, 1)] ` in the shader and `shader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, vertices.Length, 1, 1); ` the routine gives the correct result. But having so many thread groups, all with a single thread, seems to be very bad optimization...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're mistaken in the relation between threadGroups in your `Dispatch()` call, and `[numthreads()]` in your kernel specification.

The result of `shader.Dispatch(kernelHandle, vertices.Length, 1, 1);` combined with `[numthreads(32,1,1)]` is not "many thread groups all with a single thread", it is `vertices.Length` thread groups, all with 32 threads.

Your kernel will thus be invoked `32*vertices.Length` times, with `id.x` growing commensurately... you get the correct result with the code from your comment because whatever happens when you try to read and write `vertex[id.x]` after `id.x` has gone out of bounds, it doesn't alter the fact that you have by then already computed all of the correct results and stored them in the appropriate place.

**What you need to do** then in order not to waste time, is set threadGroupsX in your `Dispatch()` to `ceil(vertices.Length/32)` (pseudocode).

You could also add something like

```
if (id.x >= vertexLength) return;
```

in your kernel (because unless you happen to have a multiple of 32 vertices, some threads will be out of bounds)... but actually, that probably wouldn't help with anything in terms of performance or safety; the reads and writes outside of vertices.Length will be essentially no-ops, while the extra branching in the kernel could incur a cost.  I imagine it probably is insignificant either way in this case, and perhaps having a statement like that can make the logic clearer for human readers... but it does mean the extra boilerplate of passing in an extra uniform.

Incidentally, you may also want to use an `ASyncGPUReadbackRequest` to avoid stalling your code on `vertex.GetData(vertices);` if that makes sense in your application. You might have written it that way in the question for brevity (which as you may notice is not always my strong point).

Comment: You are right, and thank you. I’m far from being an expert at compute shaders (and shaders in general) and it’s surely not an area where you easily find tutorials or documentation....btw, out of bounds behavior is described in this book and it seems I only need to worry for  performance:   [link](https://books.google.it/books?id=gj6TDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT737&lpg=PT737&dq=compute+shader+thread+out+of+bounds&source=bl&ots=qbiqdyCzHn&sig=ACfU3U3-p6nCgqdkISEUBIIEUxKt1bTVOQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9m9nu76rjAhXD1qQKHQgPB4kQ6AEwB3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=compute%20shader%20thread%20out%20of%20bounds&f=false)

Comment: Great, thanks @kefren. Maybe the same thing also applies to my Append question. Google says I've "either reached my viewing limit or that part of the book isn't available". I just found [this](https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/archive/D3D11_3_FunctionalSpec.htm#5.3.10.2%20Using%20Unordered%20Count%20and%20Append%20Buffers) which is somewhat dense but probably has the info I need at least for DirectX.

Comment: Actually if anything, the `if (id.x >= vertexLength) return;` will do nothing but introduce an extra branch which can be bad for performance, so probably better without. I may as well edit my answer.